# Typrom postgres connetion with typescript and docker

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker, webpack, typeorm

I am trying to use typeorm in my node project. So the db is spun up via a docker. Now when the container is stopped and restarted the ip keeps changing and hence the better possibility was to make use of the container name in my configuration.

Now the real mess starts, so I tried to configure the connection options using the env variable and it seems that it cannot resolve the host (when given as a docker container).

This is my sample .env file

```
TYPEORM_HOST=postgres-container
TYPEORM_POSTGRES_USERNAME=postgres
TYPEORM_POSTGRES_PASSWORD=XXXXXX
TYPEORM_TYPE=postgres
TYPEORM_LOGGING=true
TYPEORM_SYNCHRONIZE=true
TYPEORM_DATABASE=XXXXX
PINO_ENABLE_LOGGING= true
```

This threw an error when I tried consuming it in my app stating that the host cannot be found and hence reverted back to the ip and it worked

```
   const databaseConfigParams = DatabaseConfigInstance.getConnectionParams();
    ......
   try {
            const connec = await createConnection({
                name: DB_CONNECTION_NAME,
                type: DatabaseConnectionEnum.POSTGRES,
                host: databaseConfigParams.getHost(),
                port: parseInt(databaseConfigParams.getPort()),
                username: databaseConfigParams.getUsername(),
                password: databaseConfigParams.getPassword(),
                database: databaseConfigParams.getDatabase(),
                logging: databaseConfigParams.isLogging(),
                synchronize: databaseConfigParams.isSynchronize(),
                entities: [XXXEntity, XXEntity, XXXEntity]

             });
             res(connec);
        } catch (err){
            console.log('error in creating connection:', err);
            rej(err);
        }
```

Now since the container name could not be resolved if configuration is provided as the environment var, I decided to move the configurationto ormconfig.js file.

Now where can I specify the entities to use ? . Since I use webpack to bundle my app I need the entities to be recognized even the app is bundled.

Here is my webpack config

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const dotEnvPlugin = require('dotenv-webpack');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

'use strict';

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/app/server.ts',
  mode: 'development',
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
    new UglifyJsPlugin({
        uglifyOptions: {
          keep_classnames: true,
          keep_fnames: true
        }
      })
    ],
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: [
          'ts-loader',
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.handlebars$/,
        loader: 'handlebars-loader',
        options: {
            knownHelpersOnly: false,
            inlineRequires: /\/assets\/(:?images|audio|video)\//ig,
            partialDirs: [path.join(__dirname, './src/views/email/partials')],
        },
    }
    ]

  },
  externals: [ nodeExternals() ],
  plugins: [
    new dotEnvPlugin({
        path: './config/development/.env',
        safe: true, 
        systemvars: true, 
        silent: true,
        defaults: false
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env.NODE_ENV': 'development',
        'process.env.DEBUG': 'false'
    }),

    // need this plugin for the maps to be generated
    new webpack.EvalSourceMapDevToolPlugin({
      filename: '[name].map.js'
    }),
    new webpack.WatchIgnorePlugin([
      path.join(__dirname, "node_modules")
    ]),

  ]

};
```

EDIT:

I tried using specifying entities in oemconfig.js. It works well for ts-node compilation but not after webpack.

```
module.exports = {
  name: 'postgresConnection',
  type: 'postgres',
  host: '172.17.0.3',
  port: 5432,
  username: 'postgres',
  password: 'XXX',
  database: 'XXX',
  synchronize: true,
  logging: true,
  "entities": [
      "src/app/modules/database/entities/*.ts"
  ],
};
```

So I have two issues. Not sure which approach should I take. I need to link the postgres-container (docker) and use it in my typeorm. Also I need to make the bundled code (after webpack bundle) to make use of the correct entity folder.

Answer (score 0):

I didnt try linking the postgres container on my end and that was causing the issue. Apologies as I haven't tried linking the container at my end. My bad. Now it works perfectly. I can revert to declaring the typeorm connection options in the env file and have the entities declared in the ts file itself which suits the webpack configuration

Maybe if someone also faces a similar issue this would help them
my .env file

```
TYPEORM_HOST=postgres-container
TYPEORM_POSTGRES_USERNAME=postgres
TYPEORM_POSTGRES_PASSWORD=XXXXXX
TYPEORM_TYPE=postgres
TYPEORM_LOGGING=true
TYPEORM_SYNCHRONIZE=true
TYPEORM_DATABASE=XXXXX
```

My Dockerfile ( the FROM image is my own node image. Apparently the image 12.9.0 in dockerhub is having issues with concurrency and older versions doesn't seem to support atob module base64 parsing and hence created my own from UBUNTU as base and pushed to private dockerhub)

```
FROM vijayakumarpsg587/node-12:1.01
# install pm2 and link the image using environment variables
RUN npm install pm2 -g

# Create a seperate node user
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash node-user

RUN mkdir -p /home/node/app  
# RUN chown -R node-user:node-user /home/node/app && chmod -R u+rwx,go+rwx /home/node/app
WORKDIR /home/node/app
# USER node-user
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY . ./ 


RUN npm run build:webpack:dev
ENV PM2_PUBLIC_KEY XXX
ENV PM2_SECRET_KEY XXX
```

EXPOSE 3002

CMD ["pm2-runtime", "./dist/main.js"]

Its the same webpack config. Also the ts file used to retrieve the contants from .env is also the same.

The real issue is I haven't linked the **postgres-container** to the new app container that I built.

So first I create a new app image and spin up a container

> docker build -t XXXX/XXX: .

- (.) instructs to build an image from the current Dockerfile location. builds an image with the given tag

Spin up a container from the image and while doing so link the postgres-container

```
docker run -d -p 3002:3002 --name <name of the container> --link postgres-container <image that you created earlier with the prev command>
```

EDIT: please follow the best practices from the dockerfile guidelines while writing a dockerfile. Instructions RUN,COPY ADD creates new image layers and they should be as minimal as possible. If needed be try to create multistage builds.